# How to call external webservice from GAE Java 11?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I want to move from GAE Java 8 to GAE Java 11, but the Java 11 version did away with urlfetch. There must be some way to call external urls and services from google app engine with Java 11. This seems like a fairly common need in modern apps.

Answer (score 0):

The urlfetch module of the appengine libraries (among others) were deprecated in the newer runtimes to encourage application developers to write code that could be environment independent, thus depending solely in standard java libraries. In order to  make HTTP/S request you would need to import one requests library from the many available for Java, for example [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)